# Design issue in the middle box of home page

Tags: html, css

I have site http://www.gotskinsretail.com/Dev/index.php having design problem for the middle box. When we zoom in( ctrl--), in the middle box (keep connected & win), text is coming to next line so last lines of paragraph are not shown. If i incresed the height of paragraph then share images under this paragraph coe behind the div.
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Change the element style of the pictures div to `position:absolute;` and add `bottom:0;`

This will keep the images on the bottom of your container, and the text wont move it.

Comment: but still the text in the center part ((join our newsletter, like us on  facebook------) is cut from the bottom

Comment: Increase the height of the textdiv to `150px` and change the box_image margin `3px auto`

Comment: I increased the height to 200px also, but there is issue in safari browser.

Comment: the `font-family` in your css is whats causing that problem. Using safari web inspector, i removed all of the font-family references and it fixed the problem.

Comment: i removed all the font family from the code but still is cut from the bottom

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your error? I cant seem to reproduce it anymore.